# Laravel's environment value not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I change the `APP_ENV` value from `local` to `prod` in the `.env` file, `dd(App::environment())` and `dd(env('APP_ENV'))` return `local`, while `php artisan env` returns `prod` as expected.

If I change another value e.g. `DB_HOST`, it works fine.

Do I miss anything?

```
APP_ENV=prod
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=SomeRandomString

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .env file you need to write `production` instead `prod`. hope it helps :)